# ToExpression["string",TeXForm] doesn't work

Tags: latex, expression-form

I want to convert LaTeX equation to Mathematica code.
I want to use `ToExpression["x", TeXForm]` to input some equation in Mathematica.
However, my mathemtica doesn't work that code well, just saying "$Failed"

However, other code with `ToExpression` or `TeXForm` works well.

For example, the following two are my result

[image]
[image]

But I want to do inverse process, and it fails like below.

Does anyone can help?
I am using Mathematica 11.0.

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjSVv.png Have you tried restarting the kernel?